# How to include copyright information (from a text file) using gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following task in `gulp` and I need to ADD at the beginning of my concatenated file (testApp.css) some text for copyright information.

How to achieve it in gulp?

```
 gulp.task('flat', function () {
        gulp.src(['themes/**/*.styl', '!themes/**/**mixins**.styl', '!themes/**/**variables**.styl'])
          .pipe(stylus({
              compress: true,
              use: nib()
          }))
          .pipe(concat('testAll.css'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('testx'));
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use prepend with gulp-insert

```
npm install gulp-insert
```

Used in combination with `fs`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var insert = require('gulp-insert');
var copyright = function () {
    return fs.readFileSync('copyright.txt');
};

gulp.task('flat', function () {
    gulp.src(['themes/**/*.styl', '!themes/**/**mixins**.styl', '!themes/**/**variables**.styl'])
        // Your other stuff
        .pipe(insert.prepend(copyright));
        .pipe(gulp.dest('testx'));
});
```

[Check it out on GitHub](https://github.com/rschmukler/gulp-insert) for more information.

Comment: does it work with external .txt file? Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Oh right. I should have read the question better. Give me a moment

Comment: No problems :) I have found out gulp-header for now, but if you have know another plugin please let me know.

Comment: I updated my answer. Pretty similar to using `header`, so it might not give you any benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue using `gulp-header`. Suggestion for other suitable plugins are welcome.

```
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var nib = require('nib');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var header = require('gulp-header');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('flat', function () {
    gulp.src(['themes/**/*.styl', '!themes/**/**mixins**.styl', '!themes/**/**variables**.styl'])
      .pipe(stylus({
          compress: true,
          use: nib()
      }))
      .pipe(concat('testAll.css'))
      .pipe(header(fs.readFileSync('copyright.txt', 'utf8')))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('test'));
});
```